# Positive lookbehind and lookahead failing when using plus sign as separator

Tags: .net, regex

I have the following string:

city-Rio de Janeiro+Sao Paulo+Belo Horizonte

and I'm using the following regex to try capture city names:

```
(?<=city\-|\+)(?<city>[a-zA-Z\s+\-]+)(?=\+|$)
```

unfortunelly the regex above is returning one big group, like this:

Rio de Janeiro+Sao Paulo+Belo Horizonte

if I change the separator in the source string and regex propertly everything works fine, but I would like to use the plus sign as separator, how can I do that?

Comment: Extract each city name without separator included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It matches that much because a `+` inside a character class (the square brackets) matches the literal `'+'`. Remove it:

```
(?<=city-|\+)(?<city>[a-zA-Z\s-]+)(?=\+|$)
```

and you'd get 3 matches:

1. `Rio de Janeiro`
2. `Sao Paulo`
3. `Belo Horizonte`

as the following test proves:

[image]

And a small C# test with [Ideone](http://ideone.com/tHwqc):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Example 
{
   static void Main() 
   {
      string text = "city-Rio de Janeiro+Sao Paulo+Belo Horizonte";
      string pat = @"(?<=city-|\+)(?<city>[a-zA-Z\s-]+)(?=\+|$)";

      Regex r = new Regex(pat);
      Match m = r.Match(text);

      while (m.Success) 
      {
         Console.WriteLine("found: '" + m.Groups[1] + "'");
         m = m.NextMatch();
      }
   }
}
```

produced the following output:

```
found: 'Rio de Janeiro'
found: 'Sao Paulo'
found: 'Belo Horizonte'
```

Also note that at the end of a class, and outside a character class, the `-` does not need to be escaped.

Comment: I am able to get only the second and third cities using your pattern, with input `Rio de Janeiro+Sao Paulo+Belo Horizonte`. Tested in [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm)

Comment: @DevendraD.Chavan, some regex implementations don't allow alternatives of different sizes inside a look-behind, but .NET's regex implementation is not one of them as you can see by ararog's remark. For languages that don't support this, replace `(?<=city-|\+)` by the rather verbose: `(?:(?<=city-)|(?<=\+))`

Comment: Tried the original pattern in C# .NET 3.5, still the same results (2 matches). BTW Expresso uses .NET regex. Also, tried (unsuccessfully) replacing `(?<=city-|\+)` with `(?:(?<=city-)|(?<=\+))`. Same results [here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) (not .NET).

Comment: @DevendraD.Chavan, ah, I didn't know Expresso is .NET based. But see the added screenshot of the regex and its **3** (not 2!) matches. Anyway, luckily you're not the one asking the question :)

Comment: I tested this regex here: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx, but I have to leave a note here, if you change the string to something like "blabla-Rio de Janeiro+Sao Paulo+Belo Horizonte" you will get only Sao Paulo and Belo Horizonte captured.

Comment: I'm thinking about post another question, I really need to make sure the string starts with "city-" and capture all words separated by + or  end of string match.